# Uniqueness of D'Alembert solution of wave equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

can someone help me with the following problem?

Let be $f\in{C^2\mathbb{(R)}}$ , $g\in{C^1\mathbb{(R)}}$. Then $y(t,x)=\frac{f(x+t)+f(x-t)}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}{g(r)dr}$ is a solution of wave equation with initial conditions ($y(0,x)=f(x)$,  $\delta_ty(0,x)=g(x))$ in $\mathbb{R}$. How can we prove the uniqueness of this solution?

I have found some proof of this using energy, but is there a prove which doesn't use it?

Thanks.

Comment: There are quite general proofs of uniqueness of solutions of partial differential equations, given the value on a complete boundary. I assume that $\delta_ty$ is supposed to mean $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$?

Comment: It seems that under your assumptions on the regularity of $f$ and $g$ either of the proofs in Evans' textbook gives uniqueness without recourse to energy estimates.